# PHP can't retrieve JSON from ajax call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, post

here's my JS code:

```
var person = [];
    person[0] = "John";
    person[1] = "Doe";
    person[2] = 46;
    var myData = JSON.stringify(person);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",   
        url: "test.php",
        dataType : "text", 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: myData,
        success: function(answer) {
            alert(answer);
        },
        complete: function() {
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, errorText, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR+" - "+errorText+" - "+errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

And here's php:

```
if(isset($_POST['myData']))
{
 echo "ok";
}
else
{
 echo "not_ok";
}
?>
```

And it always returns "not_ok". Why my PHP code can't retrieve JSON? What I'am doing wrong? Could anyone explain it to me?

Comment: You should use `json_encode();` !

Comment: `data: {myData : myData},`

Answer (score 1):

Try below

`dataType : "json"` : tells jQuery that you want it to parse the returned JSON

`json_encode()` : PHP function encodes array in json format.

**JavaScript**

```
var person = [];
person[0] = "John";
person[1] = "Doe";
person[2] = 46;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",   
    url: "test.php",
    dataType : "json",  // Set datatype json
    data: {myData : person}, // Request Parameters
    success: function(answer) {
        console.log(answer); // JSON Response
    },
    complete: function() {
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, errorText, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR+" - "+errorText+" - "+errorThrown);
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['myData'])){
        $status = "ok";
    }
    else
    {
        $status = "Not Ok";
    }
    echo json_encode(array("status" => $status));
    exit;
?>
```

**Output**

```
Object {status: "ok"}
```

Comment: It's me again. I was wrong.... it returns "Not ok". Dunno why, i copied and pasted your code instead of mine.

Comment: Pls write `print_r($_POST);` before `if(isset($_POST['myData'])){` and show us output

Comment: Array ( ) {"status":"Not Ok"}

Comment: Please replace `data: {'myData' : person},` with `data: {myData : person},` and let us know output

Comment: Weird. After that change it works: "Object { status: "ok" }". 
Until i added "print_r($_POST);" in php, cuz after that alert occurs: "[object Object] - parsererror - SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Comment: Pls remove `print_r($_POST);` now

Comment: Yea it fully works, i was just worried that it sends an empty array, but its ok:)
Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You need some keys to get your data from the post/get variables

```
 data:{firstname:"John",lastname:"Doe",age:45},
```

php:

```
$_POST['firstname']
```

or

`data:{data:["John","Doe",45]},`

if you really want a array

```
 $_POST['data']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are converting your array to string in json format without any name. But you can post array in ajax post, you dont need to stringify it.
you can pass your array as it is

```
data: {myData: person},



var person = [];
    person[0] = "John";
    person[1] = "Doe";
    person[2] = 46;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",   
    url: "test.php",
    dataType : "text", 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: {myData: person},
    success: function(answer) {
        alert(answer);
    },
    complete: function() {
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, errorText, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR+" - "+errorText+" - "+errorThrown);
    }
});
```